# Prolog Changing a fact into a character chain

Tags: prolog

Lets say i got 2 facts:

```
time(3:44).
time(16:28).
```

I need to find the difference between the two. So I figured If I could convert 3:44 into a character chain, I could then go threw the list, and get the numbers out and work with them....

But how can i change the fact 3:44, into a character chain?

Answer (score 1):

If your facts for `time/1` are written *precisely* as you've shown above, then they contain terms constructed with `':'/2`, such that, if you executed the following, you'd get:

```
?- time(H:M).
H = 3,
M = 44 ;
H = 16,
M = 28.
```

As you can see, you can easily extract the hours (`H`) and minutes (`M`) for each `time/1` fact using pattern matching as shown. Using this technique, you could try plugging your values into the following (n.b., this is just a suggestion; it mightn't work the way you want it to, but you should get the basic idea):

```
duration_between(H1:M1, H2:M2, H3:M3) :-
    MinsDiff is abs((M2 - M1) + ((H2 - H1) * 60)), % minutes btw H2:M2 and H1:M1
    H3 is floor(MinsDiff / 60),
    M3 is MinsDiff mod 60.
```

Exercising this, for example, gives:

```
?- duration_between(3:44, 16:28, H:M).
H = 12,
M = 44.
```

Tested with SWI-Prolog.